# Renaming a Cell in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

Is it possible to rename a cell, like "A1" to "firstCell" in C#.?am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel,

```
private void rename_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlFilename, 0, false, 5, "", "", true,                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Excel.Range r = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");

            //rename cell "A1"
           xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();       
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the name of the cell range r, something similar to

```
r.Name = "myName"
```

then you save and should be ok.

Comment: .yeah..thank you.but i tried reverse,ie I manually renamed excel cell,and did   ' string str=r.name.ToString() ' couldnt get name? any other way?